# Entity core Mapping entity types with join table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, automapper, entity-framework-core

I've started using entity core and I ran into one problem.
I'm using automapper in my project and don't know how to populate my join table(BookAuthor).

In MVC I worked with ICollections but entity core does not yet support working with many to many relationship entities and now I have to work with join table.

**Question: How can i map my Bookviewmodel to the Book?**
I don't know what should I do with my BookAuthors list. Maybe I shouldn't populate it?

I tried something like that but it's not working.

```
CreateMap<BookViewModel, Book>()
.ForMember(b => b.BookAuthors, opt => opt.MapFrom(b => b.Authors.Select(a => new BookAuthor
            {
                AuthorId = a.AuthorId
            }
```

**Models(some properties removed for brevity)**

```
 public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public List<BookAuthor> BookAuthors { get; set; }
}
public class Author
    {
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
        public List<BookAuthor> BookAuthors { get; set; }
    }
 public class BookAuthor
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
public class BookViewModel
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<AuthorViewModel> Authors { get; set; }    
}
public class AuthorViewModel
    {
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }

        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    }
public class Library : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

**The working version of the mapping**

```
 .ForMember(dto => dto.Authors, opt => opt.MapFrom(b => b.BookAuthors.Select(a=>a.Author).ToList()));
        CreateMap<List<BookAuthor>, List<AuthorViewModel>>();
.PreserveReferences()//don't forget about this row or you will get an error
.ForMember(b => b.BookAuthors, opt => opt.MapFrom(b => b.Authors
    .Select(a => new { b.BookId, Book = b, a.AuthorId, Author = a })));
```

Comment: Instead of setting `BookId = b.BookId` you should set `AuthorId = a.AuthorId`. Note, however, that this only suffices when you add a new book. Generally it is not recommended to use AutoMapper for mapping view models to entities, because that usually entails business logic that you shouldn't try to cram into a mapping configuration.

Comment: My mentor said that I shouldn't use DTO's...Adding books is just what I need. Okay i will set AuthorId, but what will I do with another 3 properties?They are null now...

Comment: I have never work with join tables, so sorry for stupid questions.

Comment: Just save the changes. EF will take care of setting the other foreign key. When you reread the books from the database, including `BookAuthors` and `Book`, EF will populate all properties.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it.

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of the `Author` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the desired mapping configuration:

```
CreateMap<Book, BookViewModel>()
    // Book -> BookViewModel
    .ForMember(b => b.Authors, opt => opt.MapFrom(b => b.BookAuthors
        .Select(ba => ba.Author)))
    .ReverseMap()
    // BookViewModel -> Book
    .PreserveReferences()
    .ForMember(b => b.BookAuthors, opt => opt.MapFrom(b => b.Authors
        .Select(a => new { b.BookId, Book = b, a.AuthorId, Author = a })))
    ;

CreateMap<Author, AuthorViewModel>()
    // Author -> AuthorViewModel
    .ReverseMap()
    // AuthorViewModel -> Author
    ;
```

The most important thing is to realize that AutoMapper does not require the **type** of the returned expression from `MapFrom` to match the type of the destination. If it doesn't match, then AutoMapper will try to map the returned type to the destination type using the corresponding mapping if any. This allows you to reuse the mappings.

In order to convert `BookAuthor` to `AuthorViewModel`, you first convert it to `Author` (by simply extracting the `Author` property) like if it was a collection of `Author`, and let AM convert the `Author` to `AuthorViewModel` using the corresponding mapping.

In order to convert `AuthorViewModel` from `BookViewModel.Authors` to `BookAuthor`, you convert it first to anonomymous type similar to `BookAuthor`, but with corresponding `Book` and `Author` property types being `ViewModel` types and let AM convert it to `BookAuthor` using corresponding mappings. `PreserveReferences()` is used to avoid stack overflow due to circular reference model.

Comment: PreserveReferences is not required anymore for a while [now](http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/5.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#circular-references).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Well, I'm with the latest AM and still getting SO exception if I don't specify `PreserveReferences`.

Comment: It doesn't work because dynamic mapping is involved. If all the maps are created statically, PreserveReferences is not needed. I don't know about fixing it, I'm not a fan of dynamic mapping.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Thank you a lot, I will test it soon(~3 days). For now, let it be the answer.

Comment: This solution isn't working for me(
Authors is still null

Comment: `Authors` is the view model property, right? And the question was for reverse map, e.g. mapping `Authors` to `BookAuthors`. Now looks like you are referring to entity -> view model map. Are you sure you retrieve the related entity data before mapping? e.g. `db.Books.Include(b => b.BookAuthors).ThenInclude(ba => ba.Author)` ?

Comment: You are right. I solved the problem a few minutes ago the same way as you said, adding ThenInclude to the retrieve data method. Sorry for inattention.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :)

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer works. AnonymousTypes aren't mapped anymore
 - https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3063. Could use a custom type instead.