# automapper and many-to-many relationship in EF core

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-code-first, mapping, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have two models with many-to-many relationship and join table:

```
 public class Book
    {
        [Key]
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
        public int YearOfPublishing { get; set; }
        public LibraryType Type { get; set; }

        public ICollection<BookPublicHouse> PublicHouses { get; set; }

        public Book()
        {
            PublicHouses = new Collection<BookPublicHouse>();
        }

    }

public class PublicHouse
    {
        [Key]
        public int PublicHouseId { get; set; }

        public string PublicHouseName { get; set; }

        public string Country { get; set; }

        public ICollection<BookPublicHouse> Books { get; set; }

        public PublicHouse()
        {
            Books = new Collection<BookPublicHouse>();
        }
    }

public class BookPublicHouse
    {
        public Book Book { get; set; }
        public int BookId { get; set; }

        public PublicHouse PublicHouse { get; set; }
        public int PublicHouseId { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I need to map View model to model.
View model looks like this:

```
 public class BookView
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
        public int YearOfPublishing { get; set; }
        public LibraryType Type { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<PublicHouseView> PublicHouses { get; set; }

    }
```

Creating map:

```
CreateMap<Book, BookView>()
                .ForMember(bv => bv.PublicHouses, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.PublicHouses.Select(y => y.PublicHouse).ToList()));
```

But I have an Exception (Error mapping types, Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
) here:

```
public IEnumerable<BookView> Get()
        {
            var books = _context.Books
                .Include(b => b.PublicHouses).ThenInclude(bph => bph.PublicHouse).ToList();
            return mapper.Map<List<Book>, List<BookView>>(books);
        }
```

Comment: Where is `PublicHouseView` class and mapping from `PublicHouse`? Also sounds like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49463501/entity-core-mapping-entity-types-with-join-table

Comment: Also show the full exception.